# Can Spring Cloud Loadbalancer be used together with Netflix Eureka instead of Netflix Ribbon?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

From the announcement of the Spring Cloud Greenwich release, see https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/23/spring-cloud-greenwich-release-is-now-available, I noticed that is recommended to replace Netflix Ribbon with Spring Cloud Loadbalancer.

Does that mean that Spring Cloud Loadbalancer can be use by a client to connect to services registered in Netflix Eureka without using Netflix Ribbon?

I have tried to find documentation and/or examples that describes how to do that, but I haven't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a sample in the tests of Spring Cloud Loadbalancer.
So what you'll have to do is the following. You'll have to annotate a configuration class with `@LoadBalancerClient` (or wrap it in `@LoadBalancerClients` if you want to have multiple clients) where you specify your client's name and its config class.
In that load balancer client's config class you'll need to create a bean which will return a load balancer. In the test it's the `RoundRobinLoadBalancer`.
You can then use that load balancer bean to pick the next service instance, which in turn can be used to make the call to your other service.

See this test: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/loadbalancer/core/LoadBalancerTest.java#L132

Comment: Thanks, very interesting!

Does there exist any integration with Spring Cloud Loadbalancer and Netflix Eureka as a Discovery service?

Or, do we have to still use Netflix Ribbon to be able to use Netflix Eureka as a Discovery service?

Comment: Better, Spring Cloud Loadbalancer works out of the box with any discovery service! :)
See following `ServiceInstanceSupplier`: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/loadbalancer/core/DiscoveryClientServiceInstanceSupplier.java

Comment: Aha, tanks again! Now I understand how it fits together, I think :-) When using the dependency to spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client we will get a EurekaDiscoveryClient setup automatically! ...and a RibbonLoadBalancerClient for a @LoadBalanced WebClient. So Ribbon is still there, but hidden under the hood as an implementation detail of the spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client? As long as we can avoid using ribbon specific configuration, it's ok with me!

Comment: Bit late to the party, but I am now working on moving to Spring Cloud Greenwich Release. I still don't find any documentation/examples on using Spring Cloud Loadbalancer. The test case above seems like an awful lot of work to configure a loadbalancer. Is there a more straight forward configuration option to get it working?
PS: I haven't yet gone through the code and explored for possible configuration options.

Comment: The provided test is checking multiple scenarios and asserting a lot which you shouldn't need to have in your production code. As of this moment there is no "straight forward configuration", but work is being put in a more out-of-the-box experience so you can easily use `@LoadBalanced` when configuring load balancing with `@LoadBalancerClient`.
Look at following snippet if you're using Spring WebClient: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-commons.adoc#spring-webflux-webclient-as-a-load-balancer-client
Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks @TYsewyn for your response. I am using RestTemplate and not WebClient. Presently I am using ```@Loadbalanced``` annotation on the RestTemplate to use Ribbon. Wondering how that changes. I am working on a small application to test out the capabilities.

Comment: You can watch this issue which tracks that functionality: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/553